# Jasper Report con Rest en Web service

Tags: java, xml, rest, servicio, jasper

Estimados tengo el siguiente problema no me permite generar el jasper con un metodo que tengo en la clase desde un servicio rest que esta recibiendo parametros por medio de un xml  o json que otra posibilidad hay de generar el reporte a partir del xml que estoy recibiendo en el servicio rest adjunto codigo

estad es la clase que recibe los parametros

public class PjudGeneraReporte {

```
static Xmlbean xmlbean;

@GET
public Xmlbean leer(){
    return xmlbean;
} 


@POST
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
public Response guardar(Xmlbean x){

    xmlbean = x;
    xmlbean.getPlantilla();

    ProcesamientoReporte PR = new ProcesamientoReporte();
    try {
        PR.GeneraReporte();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(PjudGeneraReporte.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(PjudGeneraReporte.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

esta clase no me permite generar el reporte adjunto la clase generadora de reporte

public class ProcesamientoReporte {

```
 public void GeneraReporte() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

   try{

   JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("http://localhost:8080/PJUDireportws/WEB-INF/Reportes/reportearraigo.jrxml");

   Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   parameters.clear();   

   String CRR_ARRAIGO = "505";

   parameters.put("CRR_ARRAIGO",CRR_ARRAIGO);
   JRDataSource dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,OracleConnUtils.getOracleConnection( "10.13.251.210", "RPENQA", "judpenal","lucas10.5"));  
   File outDir = new File("http://localhost:8080/PJUDireportws/");
   outDir.mkdirs();

   JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"http://localhost:8080/PJUDireportws/reporteprueba2.pdf");

   }catch(Exception e){

   return;

   }
}
```

}
esta clase genera el reporte cual seria el problema que no me genera el reporte habra otra manera de generar el reporte

Comment: este es el error que me da glassfish javax.ejb.EJBException threw a RuntimeException when attempting to obtain the response

Comment: `EJBException` es "algo malo ha pasado en el EJB" y `RuntimeException` es "algo malo ha pasado". Busca en el log la información de la excepción original, que dará la información específica y ponla en la pregunta. No te olvides indicar cuál es la línea de tu código donde se da la excepción. Ah, y aprovecha para revisar [help] y [ask].

Comment: Y `} catch (Exception e) { return; }` es ***MUY MALA IDEA***; te "comes" la información de cualquier excepción que se esté lanzando, de forma que ni siquiera sabes si ése código ha funcionado o no, y menos aún el porqué no ha funcionado.

Comment: añado los errores que me esta generando

Comment: sin el return igual me genera el error pero de alguna u otra forma no me esta generando el reporte y se cae en una parte al no generarlo